# Heating doesn't work on right hand side

Tags: vw, golf, heater-blower

The heating doesn't work on the right hand side of my 2006 Golf Plus.
It has a two different settings for left and right side, but no matter the settings, the air coming out on the right side is always cold in all places (windscreen, middle, and feet).

Is there anything I can do to diagnose or fix this?

Comment: Before you tear your dash apart to get at things you may want to find where the temperature sensor on the right is and give is a blast of compressed air

Answer (score 1):

Considering it is dual zone, the blend door motor for the right side has gone bad.

[This video may help things for you.](https://youtu.be/Iu9As1VW7sc)

You have to take the dash apart to get to the blend doors ... it looks like there's quite a bit of work involved. There's no way to my knowledge you can test the doors themselves without pulling them out and putting power to them.

Comment: seems plausible, I'll see what I can do...